# How to store each row separately with its primary key in database using php, mysql and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table, row

> I am using table to input some fields and store it in db. I used Add
>   new button to add new row if user wants to store more data, but I want
>   to store each row separately with its own primary key in table.

Below is my html code of table with add new button and jQuery for add new button:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="datatable-buttons"  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
    <thead>
      <tr class="headings">
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat">
        </th>
        <th class="column-title">Account</th>
        <th class="column-title">Debits</th>
        <th class="column-title">Credits</th>
        <th class="column-title">Description</th> 
        <th class="column-title">Name</th>                          
        <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr">Action</span>
        </th>
        <th class="bulk-actions" colspan="7">
          <a class="antoo" style="color:#fff; font-weight:500;">Bulk Actions ( <span class="action-cnt"> </span> ) <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>                                
    <tbody>
      <tr class="even pointer">
        <td class="a-center ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records">
        </td>                                    
        <td class=" "><select class="form-control" name="journalname">
          <option>Choose option</option>                   
          <?php
          $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM `chartofaccounts`');
          while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
            {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row1["name"];?>"><?php echo $row1["name"];?></option>
          <?php  }?>
        </select></td>
        <td class=""><input class="form-control" type="text" name="debit" ></td>
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="credit"></td>
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descc"></td> 
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"></td>        
        <td class=" last"><a href="#">View</a>
        </td>
      </tr>                           
    </tbody>                           
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add New</button>
</div>
```

jQuery to add new row:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#add, .check ").click(function() {
      $('#datatable-buttons tbody>tr:last')
      .clone(true)
      .insertAfter('#datatable-buttons 
      tbody>tr:last').find('input').each(function(){
      $(this).val('');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can't use same name for multiple input so just use as array name="debit[]" like this <input class="form-control" type="text" name="debit[]" >

Comment: i used array and implode function but is not working as per my conditions. currently it stores like debit1, debit2, debit3 in single row . It all 3 values should be in different rows with diffrent primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an id column in database table. You need to set this as primary key and auto increment (AI option in phpmyadmin if you are using mysql). You just need to store other data and the id column will automatically take its value which will be unique for each row.